# Flooded quarry monster revealed to be excavator

Tags: identify-this-movie

Looking for the name of this movie that I believe is from the 1980s. There is an abandoned quarry that is filled with water. A couple of kids are playing around it and discover there is something in the water. One of them may have even drowned by the supposed creature? (Can't remember.) The big reveal is that it is an excavator under the water and the scoop rises up every now and then due to gases rising from the quarry floor and collecting in the scoop.

Comment: I remember this, for some reason as a kid it blew mind I loved it! Can't remember it being Australian and I don't know why I thought it was called the go go kids.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Frog dreaming?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frog_Dreaming) It's also called [The Quest](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091810/).

> 14 year-old American kid Cody Walpole has been forced to go and live
>   in the Australian Outback with his father’s best friend following the
>   death of his parents. Cody is an enterprising inventor. He and two
>   local sisters trek up to the lake near an old disused mine, which is
>   said to contain the Donkejin or Bunyip, a creature from Aboriginal
>   legend. When the girls drift out onto the lake on a raft, Cody jumps
>   in to save them but they are attacked by a saurian monster that rises
>   to the surface. Escaping and returning to town, Cody starts to
>   research into ‘kadaicha’ or Aboriginal magic, and determines to return
>   and confront the ‘Donkejin’. When he successfully makes a suit, he dives in 
>   to explore and find the creature.
>
> In reality the creature is an old piece of mining equipment called a
>   Donkey Engine.  It’s basically an huge excavation crane that has had
>   air trapped under it causing it to life to release some of the
>   pressure from time to time.  Cody managed to find his way into the air
>   pocket underwater, and as the “creature” lift’s its head out of the
>   water he finally manages to escape to freedom.

Comment: You beat me to it. I was just writing this up. You can find the IMDB here http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091810/

Comment: @djmadscribbler "They took our jobs..." :D

Comment: Please provide a description of the movie and how you came to this answer.

Comment: I did link him to the IMDb profile. I just remember watching it. There aren't a lot of movies that have an excavator mistaken as a creature.

Comment: @DForck42, alright, let me edit that.

Comment: Just wanted to add that when I watched it as a kid in the UK it was called "The Go-Kids". The cover made it look like an action-adventure file similar to The Goonies, which of course it's actually not. I imagine they were trying to cash in on the success of that, and other similar films of the era.